# Pause video playback on Android TV when voice search is activated

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of the Live Channels app. If user presses *home* button on the remote, the app is continuing to play the video in the background. But if user presses *voice search* button on the remote, the playback is paused (but still visible behind).

Currently I'm using a method described at [Android Developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/options.html) that tells to use `requestVisibleBehind` function at `onPause` to tell weather the playback should be continued. But that keeps the video playing after search button is pressed.

I'm looking for a way to tell if the search dialog has been opened and therefore the playback of a video should be paused.

Comment: Are you getting the `onPause` event in your app?

Comment: Yes, onPause works fine. The problem is that I don't know whether it comes from home button press or microphone button press.

Comment: You could always check what key the user is pressing by overriding `dispatchKeyEvent`